# Nondimensionalizing an DE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

I am struggling to understand the validity of what is done when you have a differential equation with dimensional variables and you are able to turn it into a differential equation with less dimensional variables. To be specific, suppose you do it for the differential equation on the picture attached. I am not sure what is being done here, I don’t know if the notation of these notes is a little ambiguous but I don’t see how they are using the chain rule. Please, can someone explain it to me with unambiguous notation and not weird nonsensical differentials?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that multiplicative constants factor from derivatives, this is indeed just the chain rule: $$\frac{dc}{dt}=\frac{dc}{d\tilde{t}}\frac{d\tilde{t}}{dt}=\frac{d(C_c \tilde{c})}{d\tilde{t}} \frac{d(t/T_c)}{dt} = \frac{C_c}{T_c}\frac{d\tilde{c}}{d\tilde{t}}.$$
You could also write this as $\dfrac{dc}{dt}=\dfrac{dc/d\tilde{t}}{dt/d\tilde{t}}=\dfrac{C_c}{T_c}\dfrac{d{\tilde c}}{d\tilde{t}}$.

Comment: I don’t see where you are applying the chain rule, could you specify what the composition is?

Comment: Could you do it in Newtons notation?

Comment: It's the first equality, with the chain rule written in the usual Leibniz way. In terms of function notation, let $c=f(\tilde t)$ and $\tilde t=g(t)=t/T_c$. Then the chain rule says that differentiating $f(\tilde t)=f(g(t))$ with respect to $t$ yields $f'(g(t))g'(t)=f'(\tilde t)\cdot 1/T_c$. The remaining factor of $C_c$ comes from $c=C_c \tilde{c}$.

Comment: I don’t see it.

Comment: Why do you say that c depends on t hat and not t?

Comment: If $c$ is some function of $t$, then it's also some function of $\tilde{t}$. That's how the chain rule works: $h(x)=f(y)=f(g(x))$ implies $h'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Comment: Yes, but here we want to look for the derivative of c with respect to t, not t hat, no?

Comment: The point is they're wanting to express the derivative of $c$ with respect to $t$ _in terms of_ the derivative of $c$ with respect to $\tilde{t}$. That's precisely what the chain rule $dc/dt = (dc/d\tilde t)(d\tilde t/dt)$ does here. (One afterwards replaces $c$ with $C_c \tilde{c}$. f you like, you can write $dc/dt = d(C_c \tilde{c})/dt = C_c d\tilde c/dt$ immediately and focus on $\tilde{c}$ instead.)